# Use frontend in oauth authorisation with social auth

Tags: python, django, oauth, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

Usually, when I use social auth lib to create oauth authorisation, I sent request to some url like 127.0.0.1:8000/oauth and then it redirects me to authorisation url of auth server.
My problem is that I would like to return json with redirect url so frontend or mobile app could redirect me to it. How can I do it?